# Dimension Lookup-Update create null data on dimension table

Tags: pentaho

Dimension Lookup-Update create null data on dimension table. Anyone know how to avoid that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't.**

**Keep it**.

It avoids a lot of future referential integrity problems by providing with some kind of default in case the value of the natural key is not found.

It does not harm, because you can always query with technical key >0, if you need a list of existing cases.

Now you are warned, and if you fancy lots of NullPointerException and Foreign key integrity violation, nothing prevents you to remove the technical key =0 from the dimension table with a `Delete step`.

And an additional recommendation: do not alter the slowly dimension table to add manually an auto-increment on the technical key. Let the PDI do it's job as programmed.